# Why is Mockk failing and calling real method when doing coVerify(exactly = 0)

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

I have recently started programming in Kotlin and for writing unit test I am using Mockk library.

I am stuck at a particular point where Mockk fails while mocking a generic class.
I have a class called KafkaService which looks like this and this is also the class which I am trying to mock

```
@Service
class KafkaService<P : Any>(private val kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, String>) {

    suspend fun send(topic: String, data: P, headers: MutableMap<String, String?>, key: String? = null): SendResult<String, String>? {
        val message: Message<P> = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(data)
            .copyHeaders(headers)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topic)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.KEY, key)
            .build()
        return kafkaTemplate.send(message).join()
    }
}
```

There is another service VendorService which I am trying to test and looks somewhat like this

```
@Service
class VendorService(
    private val kafkaService: KafkaService<String>
) : Service {

    override suspend fun handle(flowToken: String, request: request) {
        .
        .
        // Some code which returns before kafkaService.send is called

        kafkaService.send(topic, payload, kafkaHeaders)
        .
        .
    }
```

Since I am testing a scenario for function handle of VendorService, in which handle function returns before calling kafkaService.send(topic, payload, kafkaHeaders)
I am doing this

```
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
class Test {
    @MockK
    lateinit var kafkaService: KafkaService<String>

        @BeforeEach
    fun init() {
        vendorService = VendorService(kafkaService)
    }

   @Test
    fun `test handle - should return before calling kafkaService`() = runBlocking {
        .
        .
        vendorService.handle(uuid, request)
        coVerify(exactly = 0) { kafkaService.send(any(), any(), any()) }
        .
        .
    }
}
```

My test fails at step where I do coVerify, the test goes inside the send function of kafkaService as if it were a real object although I have mocked it and fails with a null pointer exception because KafkaService takes KafkaTemplate<String, String> as dependency but since I am mocking KafkaService, I am not providing the dependency i.e. the dependency is null.

Am I not right in thinking that a mocked object should not call its real method, also I receive some warning logs from Mockk library which might be helpful, also in the end of the stack trace we can see the null pointer exception despite KafkaService being mocked

```
WARNING: Failed to transform class service/KafkaService
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve P from static java.lang.Object service.KafkaService.send$suspendImpl(?)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.TypeVariableSource$AbstractBase.findExpectedVariable(TypeVariableSource.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$Visitor$Substitutor$ForAttachment.onTypeVariable(TypeDescription.java:2062)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$Visitor$Substitutor$ForAttachment.onTypeVariable(TypeDescription.java:1973)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfTypeVariable$Symbolic.accept(TypeDescription.java:5931)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$Visitor$Substitutor.onParameterizedType(TypeDescription.java:1908)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$Visitor$Substitutor$ForAttachment.onParameterizedType(TypeDescription.java:1973)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfParameterizedType.accept(TypeDescription.java:5134)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterDescription$Latent.getType(ParameterDescription.java:805)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterList$AbstractBase.asTypeList(ParameterList.java:107)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$AbstractBase.hashCode(MethodDescription.java:936)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:610)
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:336)
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:121)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodRegistry$Default.prepare(MethodRegistry.java:457)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.toTypeWriter(RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.java:203)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.toTypeWriter(AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.java:122)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$UsingTypeWriter.make(DynamicType.java:4050)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3734)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InliningClassTransformer.transform(InliningClassTransformer.kt:78)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:541)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:169)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.JvmInlineInstrumentation.retransform(JvmInlineInstrumentation.kt:28)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumentation$execute$1.invoke(RetransformInlineInstrumentation.kt:19)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumentation$execute$1.invoke(RetransformInlineInstrumentation.kt:16)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.ClassTransformationSpecMap.applyTransformation(ClassTransformationSpecMap.kt:41)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumentation.execute(RetransformInlineInstrumentation.kt:16)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.inline(ProxyMaker.kt:88)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.proxy(ProxyMaker.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactory.newProxy(JvmMockFactory.kt:34)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.newProxy$default(AbstractMockFactory.kt:24)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.mockk(AbstractMockFactory.kt:59)
    at io.mockk.impl.annotations.JvmMockInitializer.assignMockK(JvmMockInitializer.kt:163)
    at io.mockk.impl.annotations.JvmMockInitializer.initMock(JvmMockInitializer.kt:41)
    at io.mockk.impl.annotations.JvmMockInitializer.initAnnotatedMocks(JvmMockInitializer.kt:24)
    at io.mockk.junit5.MockKExtension.postProcessTestInstance(MockKExtension.kt:181)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)

Cannot invoke "org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(org.springframework.messaging.Message)" because "$this.kafkaTemplate" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(org.springframework.messaging.Message)" because "$this.kafkaTemplate" is null
    at service.KafkaService.send$suspendImpl(KafkaService.kt:20)
    at service.KafkaService.send(KafkaService.kt)
```

Here are Mockk dependencies which I am using

```
    testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:4.0.0")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.3")
```

I am working on a Springboot 3.0.1 project which requires JDK 17.

Please help.

**Update**

I removed the Parameter P from KafkaService and after that the mockk test started running, also changing the class level parameter P to function level parameter of send worked fine i.e.

```
suspend fun <P> send(topic: String, data: P, headers: MutableMap<String, String?>, key: String? = null): SendResult<String, String>?
```

Comment: Is KafkaService extending some class by any chance?

Comment: No @EduardB., it has just one dependency i.e. KafkaTemplate which spring provides as stated in the question.